# Can edges have Set of properties (by set i mean multi valued atributes)

Tags: orientdb

Suppose  i have a two vertexes `A and B`.

Can the edge between this vertices have  `Set` of properties. By Set i mean Set. Not a map of key values.

EG Edge from A to B has Set tags.

I want model someting like    `A workswith B`

Now `workswith` has properties likes `ondays [monday,tuesday,friday]`

```
tags values = ['Monday','Tuesday','Friday'];
```

Here tags is a single propery but its type is Set.Is it possible?

Now will traversing i would like to find something  like

Find with all A works on monday?
Find will all A works on an day?

Note :This is a simple example depicting my use case .My real use case is more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. An edge is a document so can be very very complex with collections, maps and nested documents.

Comment: thanks very much Lvca.I know am asking too many questions these days , but the reason is i want to very sure that i can use orient DB for my use case.

Comment: No problem, this site and the official ML have this goal ;-)